# ColdFusion Builder 3 - How to not parse as XML?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

I just upgraded from ColdFusion Builder 2 to ColdFusion Builder 3. Some of my code now generates the dreaded red x, suggesting that there is an error. I know there is not an error and I would like to adjust how the editor looks at the code. It seems to be attempting to parse some cfscript as xml.

Here's the red x's that show up seemingly randomly:

[image]

Here's the error that I see when I hover over the red x:

```
syntax error
illegally formed XML syntax
syntax error
missing ; before statement
illegally formed XML syntax
```

I've looked at every relevant preference and can't find a relevant option. I've looked all over the web trying to figure out what might be causing this. What might be causing this? Is this being parsed as XML by the editor?

UPDATE - 9/11/2014

The little red error x's seem to show up randomly, even on blank lines of code.

[image: More errors]

Comment: What perspective are you using when viewing your CFML code? It's almost as if you're not using the CFML one? (disclosure: I have only used CFB3 fleetingly)

Comment: I am using the default perspective, which is ColdFusion.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are bugs in CFB3.  Please report them to https://bugbase.adobe.com/ with your code snippet

Comment: Also make sure to post your bugbase ID (with a link) so we can vote for your bug to be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The random syntax error, with descriptions on hover same as OP, is a problem I've had and reported (as an add-on to an Adobe bug already reported, with more specifics).
I'm running CFBuilder 3.0.0, Build 292922 according to the "About..." but opening the installation details shows 3.0.3.292922.
I've added the MXUnit plugin, other than that, original default installation.
I normally work in the Coldfusion or ColdFusion Debug perspective.
When I tried editing the Preferences\General\Content Types, **I was surprised to find that I only had these:
Java Class File

> Text
>   Word Document**

Highlighting "Text" showed all the files I would normally associate with web development:

*.cfc (locked)
*.cfm (locked)
*.cfml (locked)
*.css (locked)
*.htm (locked)
*.html (locked)
etc.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `cfscript` tag is using the XML style. Use the following steps to unset it:

- From the Window menu, select Preferences.
- In the tree-view, select General > Content Types.
- Expand XML in the top menu
- Remove .cfm from the menu below.

[image: XML Content Types File Associations]

In addition, make sure the doctype is not XHTML and there are no xmlns attributes.

**References**

- [Content Types Preferences page](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-content-type.htm&cp=0_4_1_15)
- [Create Custom CFML Dictionaries](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Code+Editing+in+ColdFusion+Builder#CodeEditinginColdFusionBuilder-CreatecustomCFMLdictionaries)
- [cfscript XHTML example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec19562-7fdf.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec19562-7fdf__WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec19562-7f7f)
- [How can I escape HTML character entities when using ColdFusion function XMLFormat()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187991/1113772)
- [Coldfusion Builder 3.0 Known Issues](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/release-note/known-issues-coldfusion-builder-3.html)
- [Coldfusion Builder 3.0: Quick Fix](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Code+Editing+in+ColdFusion+Builder#CodeEditinginColdFusionBuilder-QuickFix)

Comment: I found the first three of your points easily. I couldn't make sensse of the fourth one though: "Change the xmlstyle property of the cfscript tag to false in the selected dictionary".  Can you explain that?

Comment: @EvikJames Sorry. The simple way is to go to ColdFusion > Profiles > Editor > Syntax Checking. Then deselect Enable Syntax Checking.

Comment: Paul, I made the change you suggest. No help. The errors occur when not in CFSCRIPT. I added an image above.

Comment: @EvikJames If this is a .cfm file, go to Window > Preferences > General > Content Types. Expand `XML` in the top menu, then remove .cfm from the menu below. I've added a screenshot above.

Answer (score 1):

CFBuilder is responding to the javascript in the cfm.  In my case, I saw similar behavior even though the document where I was seeing the red "X"s simply had an "include".  However, since I had  tags inside the included template, the errors were appearing in the calling page.  Either way, it's the script tags lacking a "type" attribute which is causing the red Xs to appear, and those red Xs bubble all the way up to any page including the template where the javascript occurs.

In my case, I added  `type="application/javascript"`to the tag like so:

`<script type="application/javascript" >`

The red Xs then disappeared.

I hope that helps.